# Why do i see a question in pink color?

Tags: support, tags

[image]

Why is the question in the mid colored pink?

I have been watching this from about an hour or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably one of your favorited or frequented tags.

[image]

If you don't have any favorite tags, it will auto-choose your frequented tags(I think this was fixed, not sure). Auto favorite a nonexistant tag (I do [frequentedtagsfail](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequentedtagsfail)) if you want the pink to go away.

Comment: Yep! it has gone.